# vsphere: 2 separate terminal windows

Tags: vmware-vsphere, terminal

Simple issue. Is it possible in vSphere to view 2 separate terminal windows into the same VM?  I know you can switch between terminal instances using ALT+Right/ALT+Left, but I can't find a way to be viewing two separate terminals at the same time.

This is necessary because I need to modify network states in one terminal while watching a log in another.  SSH isn't an option because when I bring the network down, the SSH connection would be severed.

EDIT: I should point out I have no desktop environment on the guest.  It's a Linux Server OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible in VSphere, but maybe the split screen functionality of `screen` or `tmux` will help you with this.

Comment: How would I go about that?  I should point out I have no desktop environment on the guest.

Comment: I assume you have a Linux guest. You just install `screen` or `tmux` into it, start it and split the screen as described in the manual page of the tool (I recommend `tmux` for this, it has better split screen support). Both tools work in the terminal.

Comment: using `tmux`, it's `CTRL+b, "` to split the screen horizontally.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean can you have two vsphere client/web-clients viewing the same console/frame-buffer at the same time? if then yes, just open them up, you can have 8 in fact. The only downside is that it does moan about it with a message at the top of each screen if two or more sessions are active.

Comment: no, I need 2 windows into 2 different consoles.  see Sven's answer and my comment